# Does change of password require re-encryption whole partition in BitLocker?

Tags: windows, bitlocker

I would like to ask whether change of BitLocker password requires reencryption of whole partition? My encrypted partition is 800GB big and it would take a lot of time. If re-encryption is not required, how it is possible and how does it work then?

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that it would not require a re-encryption.  The password simply provides access to the encryption key.  When you change your password it won't change the encryption key, simply the access to it.

The key is required to decrypt your data, and the key is protected via the password.